# Using Gradle 6 to build an additional artifact that avoids split packages

Tags: java, gradle, java-module

I have a Gradle 6.5 project `bar` that has several subprojects and uses split packages, which I cannot remove in the current configuration.

I want to package an additional `bar-all` artifact that declares an automatic module name via MANIFEST.MF

```
Automatic-Module-Name: com.foo.bar
```

and contains all the classes from all the subprojects. The main purpose of this additional artifact is for use in modular applications and to avoid the split package problem.

I suspect I need to take the build outputs of the other subprojects and reuse them in a custom Jar task within `bar-all` but can't find a good example of this.

Comment: „*…The main purpose of this additional artifact is…to avoid the split package problem…*“— [*I solved another split package problem recently*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072627/understanding-errors-with-jpms-modules/64124282#64124282). I'm late to the party. So I presume you will have already found a solution by now. But if you're interested anyway, I could help you apply that same plugin to an [*MRE*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that you push to a repo.

Answer (score 0):

for a sample structure below, where top project is dependent on all sub projects - so top builds the uber jar

```
top 
 |___spa
 |___spb
 |___spc
 |___spd
 |___spe
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'top'

include 'spa', 'spb', 'spc', 'spd', 'spe'
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation project('spa')
    implementation project('spb')
    implementation project('spd')
    implementation project('spe')

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre'
}

task jarAll(type: Jar, dependsOn: jar) {
    archiveClassifier = 'all'
    from sourceSets.main.output
    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.allDependencies.findAll { it instanceof ProjectDependency }.collect { it.dependencyProject.sourceSets.main.output }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes (
            "Automatic-Module-Name": "com.foo.bar" )
    }
}
```

the top-all.jar will include the classes from the sub-projects;

Comment: Some of this (e.g. configurations.runtimeClasspath.allDependencies) appears to be deprecated / unavailable in Gradle 6. I'm using a Kotlin build script though, so it's possible I'm not transliterating it into Kotlin properly, though.